# Ubuntu software for watching downloaded tv shows?

Tags: ubuntu, video-player

I am looking for software that will display shows you have downloaded along with a cover for them, similar to "lutris" in the way that it would list all shows you have downloaded,
categorize them to your liking (not necessary) allow you to display covers for the shows, and play them.
I can also settle for a web app.

Comment: Have you check VLC?

Comment: VLC only offers playing the video, what I'm looking for is a gui that will also display the videos in sort of playlists and such

Comment: With VLC you can create and play playlists, check with Media->Open file and select from extensions menu playlists

Comment: Maybe a media center software like [Jellyfin](https://jellyfin.org/) would fit?

Answer (score 1):

Seconding [@Izzy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/80588/ubuntu-software-for-watching-downloaded-tv-shows#comment98634_80588) with [Jellyfin](https://jellyfin.org/) and adding [Plex](https://plex.tv) as another alternative

With Plex (proprietary-freemium) being the current leader in self-hosted media library player-management, and Jellyfin a very-good completely FOSS alternative to it.

For GUI based application, you have [KODI](https://kodi.tv/) as the golden standard. Completely FOSS.

All of these solutions can handle what you've asked for: Automatic downloading of meta-data, cover art, trailer association (form online resources like youtube) usually based on the file-name.
These features are either completely built-in out of the box, or require some easily configurable addons.

Bonus tip: Tying a good media-player with the [Servarr](https://wiki.servarr.com/) echo-system for managing downloads can be a complete quality-of-life game-changer.